# How to use random.choice for two lists and compare random indexes from list 1 to the random indexes of list 2

Tags: python

I am trying to get input the names of each worker and whether they have paid or not. I have created two empty list one for workers_name and one paid_or_not. In for loop I am appending this list with the user input. I am struggling how to compare workers_name index with paid_or_not list index. So if 'Jhon' paid and 'Sarah' not paid the program should display Jhon win. I can understand both list generating randomly and can't retrieve same index from other list.

**Here is my Code:**

```
import random

workers_name = []

paid_or_not = []


x = 0

for x in range(5):
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    workers_name.append(name)

    payment = input("paid or not paid, Enter Yes or No: ")
    paid_or_not.append(payment)


workers_name1 = random.choice(workers_name)
print(workers_name1)


paid_or_not1 = random.choice(paid_or_not)
print(paid_or_not1)


if paid_or_not1 == "yes":
    print(workers_name1, "get winnings")

elif paid_or_not1 == "no":
    print(workers_name1, "not get winnings and money should go to charity")
```

**Here is output**

```
Enter your name: Tania
paid or not paid, Enter Yes or No: no
Enter your name: Jhon
paid or not paid, Enter Yes or No: yes
Enter your name: Edward
paid or not paid, Enter Yes or No: yes
Enter your name: Juilian
paid or not paid, Enter Yes or No: no
Enter your name: Steve
paid or not paid, Enter Yes or No: yes
Tania
yes
Tania get winnings
```

From the output we can see Tania didn't paid but its showing paid. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you're selecting the elements from `workers_name` and `paid_or_not` independently, so it's not surprising that the resulting values have nothing to do with each other. Here are two suggestions for what you could do differently.

You could select one *index* randomly, and use that index to select the corresponding items from both lists:

```py
idx = random.randrange(len(workers_name))
worker = workers_name[idx]
paid = paid_or_not[idx]
```

Or you could associate the elements right at the start when they are created, for example in a dictionary:

```py
paid_or_not = {}
for x in range(5):
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    payment = input("paid or not paid, Enter Yes or No: ")
    paid_or_not[name] = payment

worker, paid = random.choice(list(paid_or_not.items()))
```